# SQL query not working with forward slash - Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

I am trying to execute an sql query in oracle database (the query should return the month number), when I use dates values it works :

```
select substr(to_char('8/19/2015 9:40:32 AM'), 1, instr(to_char('8/19/2015 9:40:32 AM'), '/', 1, 1)-1)
       from table_name t1
```

but when I use column names instead of dates it does not return results:

```
  select substr(to_char(t1.creation_date), 1, instr(to_char(t1.creation_date), '/', 1, 1)-1)
       from table_name t1
```

even when i escape it:

```
  select substr(to_char(t1.creation_date), 1, instr(to_char(t1.creation_date), q'[/]', 1, 1)-1)
       from table_name t1
```

Hope you can help me!

Thanks in advance

Comment: select to_char(column_name,'mm') from table_name  it will return month number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below :

```
select to_char(to_date('15-11-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'MM') from dual
```

will return you below output :

```
11
```

For column names :

```
select to_char(t1.creation_date, 'MM') from table_name t1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select to_number(to_char(t1.creation_date,'mm')) from table_name t1
```